# Using "match_recognize" in a Common Table Expression in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

Update: This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544567/match-recognize-with-cte-in-snowflake/68550312#68550312).

I am putting together a somewhat complex query to do event detection, join(s), and time-based binning with a large time-series dataset in Snowflake. I recently noticed that `match_recognize` lets me eloquently detect time-series events, but whenever I try to use a `match_recognize` expression within a Common Table Expression (`with .. as ..`), I receive the following error:

> SQL compilation error: MATCH_RECOGNIZE not supported in this context.

I've done a lot of searching/reading, but haven't found any documented limitations on `match_recognize` in CTEs. Here's my query:

```
with clean_data as (
    -- Remove duplicate entries
    select distinct id, timestamp, measurement
    from dataset
),

label_events as (
    select *
    from clean_data
        match_recognize (
            partition by id
            order by timestamp
            measures
                match_number() as event_number
            all rows per match
            after match skip past last row
            pattern(any_row row_between_gaps+)
            define
                -- Classify contiguous sections of datapoints with < 20min between adjacent points.
                row_between_gaps as datediff(minute, lag(timestamp), timestamp) < 20
        )
)

-- Do binning with width_bucket/etc. here
select id, timestamp, measurement, event_number
from label_events;
```

And I get the same error as above with this.

Is this a limitation that I'm not seeing, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68550312/132438

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Thanks for linking it.

Comment: cool! please share the answer if you have it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this thread from a comment by Filipe Hoffa: [MATCH_RECOGNIZE with CTE in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544567/match-recognize-with-cte-in-snowflake/68550312#68550312)

This seemed to be a non-documented limitation of Snowflake at the time. A two or three step solution has worked well for me:

```
with clean_data as (
    -- Remove duplicate entries
    select distinct id, timestamp, measurement
    from dataset
)

select *
from clean_data
    match_recognize (
        partition by id
        order by timestamp
        measures
            match_number() as event_number
        all rows per match
        after match skip past last row
        pattern(any_row row_between_gaps+)
        define
            -- Classify contiguous sections of datapoints with < 20min between adjacent points.
            row_between_gaps as datediff(minute, lag(timestamp), timestamp) < 20
    );

set quid=last_query_id();

with label_events as (
    select *
    from table(result_scan($quid))
)

-- Do binning with width_bucket/etc. here
select id, timestamp, measurement, event_number
from label_events;
```

I prefer to use a variable here, because I can re-run the second query multiple times during development/debugging without having to re-run the first query.

It is also important to note that cached GEOGRAPHY objects in Snowflake are converted to GEOJSON, so when retrieving these with `result_scan`, you must typecast them back to the GEOGRAPHY type.

Answer (score 2):

Non-recursive cte could be always rewritten as inline view:

```
--select ...
--from (
select id, timestamp, measurement, event_number
from (select distinct id, timestamp, measurement
     from dataset) clean_data
match_recognize (
        partition by id
        order by timestamp
        measures
            match_number() as event_number
        all rows per match
        after match skip past last row
        pattern(any_row row_between_gaps+)
        define
            -- Classify contiguous sections of datapoints with < 20min between adjacent points.
            row_between_gaps as datediff(minute, lag(timestamp), timestamp) < 20
    )mr
-- ) -- if other transformations are required
```

It is not ideal, but at least it will allow query to run.

Comment: True; thanks for the answer. This is the solution I'm using currently, but I'm hoping to avoid it for the sake of code readability. What I want to do after the `match_recognize` step involves some branching computations with a join at the end. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @natador Depends on the complexity of cte. But you could always try to materialize part of cte as temporary table and based on that build the rest of the logic.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68550312/132438